How can I add box plots in my circular graph in R
I couldnt handle the circular data. Even though december and january are close in a circular context, the box plot extends around the entire circle and doesn't properly reflect their continuity.How can I fix the problem?
# Necessary libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(geomtextpath)

# Initial dataset with egg laying, hatching, and observation dates
df <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2019-01-08", "2023-01-18", "2023-01-18", "2024-01-21", 
                   "2018-12-30", "2023-03-31", "2023-12-27", "2024-02-24")),
  location = c("Obs1", "Obs2", "Obs3", "Obs4", "Obs5", "Obs6", "Obs7", "Obs8")
)

# Calculate hatching and egg laying dates
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    hatching_date = date - weeks(5),
    egg_laying_date = hatching_date - weeks(4)
  )

# Transform data to long format
df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(date, hatching_date, egg_laying_date), 
               names_to = "date_type", values_to = "event_date") %>%
  mutate(
    month_shifted = (month(event_date) - 1) %% 12 + 1,  # Shift months so January is the start
    day_of_year_shifted = ((yday(event_date) + 0) %% 365) / 365,  # Adjust days for circular plot
    y_offset = case_when(
      date_type == "date" ~ 1,
      date_type == "hatching_date" ~ 0.85,    # Hatching slightly inward
      date_type == "egg_laying_date" ~ 0.75   # Egg laying further outward
    )
  )

# Create the circular plot with shifted dates
ggplot() +
  # Add month labels around the circle, starting from January as month 1
  geom_textpath(data = data.frame(x = seq(0.5/13, 12.5/13, length.out = 12), 
                                  y = 1.1, label = month.abb),
                aes(x, y, label = label), size = 5, color = "darkgrey") +
  # Add month dividers
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(x = seq(0, 11) / 12, xend = seq(0, 11) / 12,
                                 y = 0.55, yend = 1.15),
               aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), color = "grey50", linetype = "dashed") +
  # Add individual points for each event type
  geom_point(data = df_long, aes(x = day_of_year_shifted, y = y_offset, color = date_type), size = 3) +
  # Add labels for observation points
  geom_text(data = df_long %>% filter(date_type == "date"), aes(x = day_of_year_shifted, y = 1.2, label = location), size = 3) +
  # Add box plots based on date types and align them correctly
  geom_boxplot(data = df_long, aes(x = day_of_year_shifted, y = y_offset, fill = date_type, group = date_type),
               width = 0.05, alpha = 0.3, outlier.shape = NA) +
  # Customize colors and legend
  scale_color_manual(values = c(date = "red", hatching_date = "blue", egg_laying_date = "green")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(date = "red", hatching_date = "blue", egg_laying_date = "green")) +
  # Polar coordinates for circular layout
  coord_polar() +
  # Additional theme adjustments
  theme_void() +
  labs(title = "Circular Timeline with January at the Top", color = "Date Type", fill = "Date Type") +
  theme(legend.position = "right")

I have tried some manipulation like make the start the year from september, that fix the problem in my case but if the data split all around the year it may not help. I need more solid solve.
Image link of the graph:IMAGE

Just a note: area-related geometries on a circular plot are highly prone to misinterpretation. E.g. the area of a box spanning two months on the outer part of the graph will be much larger than the area of a box spanning the same two months, in the inner part of the graph. This suggests that the dispersion of values on the outer geometry is larger than the one on the inside, which might not be true.

It is possible to make a polar coordinate plot where elements can span the December - January period with coord_radial.
here's an example:
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

# show 1 month segments in a polar(radial) coordinate system

df <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2021-01-01", 
                   "2022-02-27",
                   "2023-03-12",
                   "2024-04-16",
                   "2025-05-20",
                   "2026-06-02",
                   "2027-07-30",
                   "2028-08-15",
                   "2029-09-20",
                   "2030-10-25",
                   "2031-12-30",
                   "2032-12-15"
                   )),
  label = letters[1:12]
)

# use lubdridate to get the date interval between the min and max of df$date
# add a month, to include the month from that last date
span <- interval(min(df$date), max(df$date)+months(1))

# duration of the interval
dur <- as.duration(span)

# number of years in the interval
n_years <- as.numeric(dur, "years")

# create the breaks for the x axis, one break for every month
# every month since the first of df$date for 1 year()
start = min(df$date)

# end = start + 1 year + 1 month (to include the last month)
end = start + years(1) + months(1)
xbreaks <- seq(start, end, by = "1 month")

# there are only 12 months in a year, so we only need 12 breaks
xbreaks <- xbreaks[1:12]

xlimits = c(min(df$date), max(df$date) + months(1))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(
      x = date, xend = date+months(1), 
      y = year(date), yend = year(date+months(1)), 
      color = label
      ), 
  linewidth = 2
  ) +
  # the panel gris is foobar'd in this plot, so we'll just draw our own
  geom_hline(
    yintercept = c(2020.5, 2025.5, 2030.5, 2035.5), 
    color = "grey", linetype = "solid", linewidth = .1
    ) +
  # mark the beginning of each segment
  geom_text(
    aes(x = date, y = year(date), label = label), 
    color = "black"
    ) +
  coord_radial(
    theta = "x", 
    start = 0, 
    # this is to make repating months in a circle 
    end = 2*pi*n_years,
    direction = 1, 
    clip = "off", 
    expand =  FALSE, 
    inner.radius = .5
    )+
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = as.numeric(xbreaks), 
    limits = as.numeric(xlimits), 
    labels = format(xbreaks, "%b")
    )+
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = c(0, 0), 
    limits = c(2020, 2035.5)
    )+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(
    # don't draw the panel grid
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  )
  
  

